# Coloring edges of a graph according to their weight?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

What's the simplest way to plot a graph with weighted edges, such that the color of the edge corresponds to the weight of the edge?

Comment: Why the downvote? Please leave a comment

Comment: The evildoer was me, because I felt that an estimated contributor like yourself should have shown some own efforts.

Comment: @eldo I really did not know how to get started, so I had nothing to show.

Comment: Accepted @ becko

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update:** If the graph `g1` is already created, I think `SetProperty` is the most convenient way to make changes in `g1`:

```
g1 = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, EdgeWeight -> {2, 3, 4}];
ew = PropertyValue[g1, EdgeWeight];
el = EdgeList[g1];
edgestylea = Thread[el -> (Directive[CapForm["Round"],
        Thickness[Rescale[# , Through@{Min, Max}@ew, {0.02, .06}]],
        ColorData[1, #]] & /@ ew)];
edgestyleb = Thread[el -> (Directive[CapForm["Round"],
        Thickness[.02 + .04 #], (* or Thickness[Rescale[#, {0,1}, {.02,.06}]] *)
        ColorData["SolarColors"][#]] & /@ Rescale[ew])];

g1a = SetProperty[g1, EdgeStyle -> edgestylea];
g1b = SetProperty[g1, EdgeStyle -> edgestyleb];
Row[{g1a, g1b}]
```

[image]

If not, you can directly use the edge-weight information for styling edges:

```
el = {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1};
ew = {2, 3, 4};
edgestylea = Thread[el -> (Directive[CapForm["Round"],
        Thickness[Rescale[# , Through@{Min, Max}@ew, {0.02, .06}]],
        ColorData[1, #]] & /@ ew)];
edgestyleb = Thread[el -> (Directive[CapForm["Round"],
        Thickness[.02 + .04 #],
        ColorData["SolarColors"][#]] & /@ Rescale[ew])];

g2a = Graph[el, EdgeWeight -> ew, EdgeStyle -> edgestylea];
g2b = Graph[el, EdgeWeight -> ew, EdgeStyle -> edgestyleb];
Row[{g2a, g2b}]
(* same picture *)
```

---

**Original Post**

One possible approach: use the `EdgeWeight` `PropertyValue` of an edge with `EdgeStyle`

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, EdgeWeight -> {2, 3, 4},
     EdgeStyle -> {e_ :> 
                Directive[Thick, ColorData[1, PropertyValue[{g, e}, EdgeWeight]]]}]
```

[image]

Or

```
h = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, EdgeWeight -> {2, 3, 4}];
SetProperty[h, EdgeStyle -> Thread[EdgeList[h] ->
            (Directive[Thick, ColorData[1, #]] & /@  PropertyValue[h, EdgeWeight])]]
(* same picture *)
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't realise you could use patterns in `EdgeStyle`. FYI you can use `<->` for a slightly more readable UndirectedEdge.

Comment: Thank you @Simon. I cannot find this usage pattern in the docs; I must have learned it somewhere on this site.

Answer (score 4):

> What's the simplest way...

I think the simplest way is with [the IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).

```
ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "EastAfricaEmbassyAttacks"}] //  
  Graph[#, EdgeStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5]] & // (* thicken edges *)
  IGEdgeMap[ColorData["Rainbow"], EdgeStyle -> Rescale@*IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight]] (* colour edges *)
```

[image]

Notice how setting `EdgeStyle` individually for each edge (to colour them) did not remove the global `EdgeStyle` setting that adjusts thickness.  I am pointing this out because this behaviour is far from obvious (in fact to me it is counterintuitive), but it can be very useful.

The setting stored inside the graph looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Disclosure: I'm the package author. While this looks like a plain advertisement, I really do think that this technique considerably simplifies the task of styling graphs based on their attributes. I use it regularly.